# Testing ReduxForm with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, redux-form

How can I test my Redux-Form component?
 I have this test:

```
describe('<SignIn />', () => {
    let wrapper, store;
    const props = {isWidthSmallThan750: true, classes: {}};

    beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore({});
        wrapper = mountComponent(SignUp, props); //equal to mount(Component)
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        wrapper = null;
        store = null;
    });

    it('snapshot testing', () => {
        expect(componentToJSON(SignIn, props)).toMatchSnapshot(); //equal to render.create(Component).toJSON
    })

    it('when form submitted, these actions may happen', () => {
        const form = wrapper.find('form');
        wrapper.find('input').at(0).simulate('change', {target: {value: 'Tigran'}});
        wrapper.find('input').at(1).simulate('change', {target: {value: 'Tigran'}});
        expect(wrapper.find('input').at(0).props().value).toBe('Tigran');
        expect(wrapper.find('input').at(1).props().value).toBe('Tigran');
        form.simulate('submit');
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(null);
    })
});
```

But when form.simulate is called I didn't get my onSubmit function call.
**How can I solve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Try `wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');` instead of `form.simulate('submit')`.

Newest versions of enzyme cache results so the state of it might be stale.

Also try `wrapper.find('form').props().submit()`. I highly recommend you don't use simulate and jut call it directly, simulate is flaky.

Comment: And in case wrapper.find('form').props().submit() throwing error.

Comment: onSubmit not submit(). Don't know why it's not working. Somewhere else in your code must be wrong

Comment: props() is not a function